# Trying to build a widget using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, widget

I'm currently working on a widget using javascript and jquery. Now what I want to create a widget button that when clicked, will start a chat with the person whose id is associated with the widget. On the main website it's just a call to the function that does that but with the widget I don't really know how to do it since I can't call my function from another website.

I've read a few tutorials on creating jquery widgets but I didn't fully grasp them because it seems that what the tutorial was teaching was to retrieve data from the host server which isn't really my intention. Also they quoted the use of JSON which I don't also fully grasp as it seems that JSON is a way of displaying objects and strings.

Anyway I need some guidance on how to achieve this.

So far this is what I put down :

```
 (function () {
     var jQuery;

     if (window.jQuery == undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.8.1') {
         var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
         script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
         script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js");

         if (script_tag.readyState) {
             script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
                 if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                     scriptLoadHandler();
                 }
             };
         } else {
             script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
         }
         (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
     } else {
         jQuery = window.jQuery;
         main();
     }

     function scriptLoadHandler() {
         jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
         main();
     }

     function main() {
         jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
             var homeURL = 'http://www.reflap.com/';

             var css_link = $("<link>", {
                 rel: "stylesheet",
                 type: "text/css",
                 href: homeURL + "assets/widget.css"
             });

             var $container = ('#mywebsite-container');
             css_link.appendTo('head');

             $.getJSON(homeURL + 'assets/js/anonymous.js', function (response) {
                 $container.append(response.html);
             });

         });

     }
 })();
```

NEW EDIT

This is what I attempted before.

The function in question is call chat and it takes 3 parameters.

So my first widget looked like this

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/chatter.js"></script><a href="#"        

onclick="Chatter.chat('1','user', null)" id="chat-widget">Chat now</a>
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're doing, but you're probably running into the AJAX Same-Origin restriction.

Comment: I haven't really even done anything. I basically started off with the code I read from the tutorial and I'm stuck moving forward on what I want to do.

Comment: What's your question, then? We can't help you fix code that you haven't written. JSON has nothing to do with widgets, it's just a way of getting data from the server if that's what the purpose of the widget happens to be. If your widget does something else, put that in the widget code.

Comment: If it need to call your function, include your function in the file.

Comment: @Barmar I just added my first attempt in the original question.

Comment: You need to post your definition of `Chatter` if you expect us to help you with it. BTW, you probably don't need to do all that stuff to dynamically load jQuery. Just write in your documentation that jQuery is a prerequisite to use your widget, that's what all the plugins do.